# No sound after suspending Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sound, mouse, shutdown, suspend, hibernate

This problem is already known but the given solution didn't work for me. When I suspend Ubuntu, in resume I don't have sound. The solution that work for is to force shut down (by pressing the power on button for 5 seconds). Restarting or shutting down the computer normally doesn't help. I've got similar problem when I restart from Linux to Windows, I don't have mouse. The solution to get back the mouse is also to force shut down. I thought that problem is Windows 8 but now I'm sure that is Ubuntu

Can someone could help or explain me the difference between force shut down and normal shut down. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What hardware are you using? And what drivers for the audio devices etc - you can use `lspci -v` to find out.

Comment: [Restarting pulseaudio may work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=816159) - though using `start-pulseaudio-x11` command to start it may work better after killing it.  Also, does the sound work after resume if you login as another user?

Comment: @wilf here there result of command http://pastebin.com/4pxEk2fp, I haven't tried your second option as I'm the only user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reported this as a bug in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1258960 and the problem was fixed in kernel 3.13.